# Android 4.4.4 SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 3850)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have the following crash

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error (code 3850): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Category WHERE IsVehicle = 1
```

The line that generate this exception is

```
Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

I also notice that all three crashes from only one type of device which is

Device : SAMSUNG GT-i9060i
Android OS : 4.4.4

Can any one tell me what is the problem with this device? and what should I do?

**EDIT**

```
private static Q8CarDBHelper mInstance;
    private Context mContext;

    private Q8CarDBHelper(Context context, String dbPath) {

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
        DB_PATH = dbPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure disc is not full

Comment: @RahulTiwari : Thanks for your reply, but I found the following description to error 3850 [The SQLITE_IOERR_LOCK error code is an extended error code for SQLITE_IOERR indicating an I/O error in the advisory file locking logic. Usually an SQLITE_IOERR_LOCK error indicates a problem obtaining a PENDING lock. However it can also indicate miscellaneous locking errors on some of the specialized VFSes used on Macs.], so it is seems to be lock database problem although I don't know why or how to solve it.

Comment: if that's the case then try making your DB helper singleton. that might help.

Comment: @RahulTiwari My Data base helper is singleton already please check post edit.